# Prove summation $\log(i)$ for $i=1$ to $i=n$ belongs to big-omega$(n(\log(n)))$

Tags: summation, proof-writing, logarithms

am looking to prove that lg(n!) belongs to BigOmega(nlgn) using the fact that log(n!) >= (n/2)lg(n/2)

now ay have an idea that lg(n!) = sum(i=1 to n) of lg(i) >= sum(i=n/2 to n) of lg(i) >= sum(i=1 to n) of lg(n/2) = (n/2)lg(n/2)

Now ay wanna show the original inequality using this fact.

Ay saw a solution but it involved using calculus and doesnt use (n/2)lg(n/2).

(sry have a problems with writing personal pronouns that ay dont wanna talk about)

Thank you for any help

Comment: the farthest ay got was
log(n!) >= (n/2)lg(n/2) = 1/2(n.lg(n/2)) = 1/2(n.lg(n) - n.lg(2))

Comment: Look at the links on the right. This has been asked many times.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/939798/450972

Comment: It doesnt tell how (n/2)lgn(n/2)=Ω(nlgn)

Answer (score 0):

You've shown that $$
\log(n!) \ge \frac{n}{2} \log \frac{n}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \left ( n \log n -
 n \log 2 \right ).
$$

(I'm using "log" here to denote log base 2.)

For $n > 2^2$, we have $\log n > 2$, while $\log 2 = 1$. So for $n > 2^2$, we have $\log 2 < \frac{\log n}{2}$. Hence
$$
\log n - \log 2 \ge \frac{1}{2} \log n. 
$$

Subsituting this in the formula above, we get
$$
\log (n!) \ge \frac{n}{2}(\log n - \log 2) \ge \frac{n}{2}(\frac{\log n}{2})
$$
hence
$$
\log (n!) \ge \frac{1}{4} (n \log n)
$$
and hence it's in $\Omega(n \log n)$.